# Conjugacy class that is not closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm reading Springer's Linear algebraic group and I stuck with one exercise.

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic 2 and let $G = \mathrm{SL}_{2}$. Then it says that conjugacy class of the matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
is not closed in $G$. By hand, I can show that the conjugacy class is 
$$
\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1-ac & a^{2} \\ - c^{2} & ac+1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1+ ac & a^{2} \\ c^{2} & 1+ac \end{pmatrix}\,:\, a, c\in k\right\}.
$$
How can we show that the set is not topologically closed in $G$?

Comment: @MJD I mean that the set is not closed topologically, not closed under the group operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: there exists a particularly simple matrix which isn't in this orbit which should be. You've missed one condition on $a,c$ when you say that $a,c\in k$ (can they both be zero at the same time?).

Comment: I think I got it, but can you explain how to prove it rigorously? So $a, c$ can't be both zero, and when $a=c=0$, the matrix became an identity matrix, and this case is a sort of "limit point" intuitively. How to prove that the closure of the conjugacy class contains the identity element?

Comment: Find the ideal of functions $I$ which vanish on the conjugacy class. Show that the identity matrix is inside $V(I)$. Since $V(I(X))=\overline{X}$ for any subset $X$ of a variety, you've shown that the identity matrix is in the closure of the conjugacy class. (As a check, the given orbit is picked out by the matrices of zero trace.)